# Override Multiple Spring Application Properties

Tags: java, spring

I am creating simple Spring apps using Maven and have 2 config and properties. The hierarchy is:

```
- package.main
  - App.java
  - AppConfig.java
  - app.properties
- package.main.model
  - ModelConfig.java
  - model.properties
```

**App.java**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
    System.out.println(applicationContext.getEnvironment().getActiveProfiles()[0]);
}
```

**AppConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@Import(ModelConfig.class)
@PropertySource("classpath:/package/main/app.properties")
public class AppConfig {}
```

**app.properties**

```
spring.profiles.active = prod
```

**ModelConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/package/main/model/model.properties")
@ComponentScan
public class ModelConfig {}
```

**model.properties**

```
spring.profiles.active = dev
```

1. Why the `model.properties` is override the `app.properties` (the result is `dev`)?
2. How to make `application.properties` like in Spring Boot that cannot overrode by new properties?

Answer (score 0):

it is by the order of beans defined being ModelConfig loaded it will cause the active profile to be set for 'dev'.

BTW, looking at your setup, configuring the active profile of beans via properties file like this not the good idea though, [spring.profiles.active should be specified in](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-set-active-spring-profiles)

**application.properties**
file, not to loaded via separate property files, so when application starts it loads the bean correctly for the profile

or **via command line arguments** when you invoke

```
-Dspring.profiles.active
```

or programmatically

context.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("live");

some good examples [here](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-profiles-example/)